# Sharding with replication

Tags: mongodb, galera, cockroachdb, citus, vitess

[Sharding with replication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUYpX.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUYpX.jpg)

I have a multi tenant database with 3 tables(store,products,purchases) in 5 server nodes .Suppose I've 3 stores in my store table and I am going to shard it with **storeId** .
I need all data for all shards(1,2,3) available in nodes 1 and 2. But node 3 would contain only shard for store #1 , node 4 would contain only shard for store #2 and node 5 for shard #3. It is like a sharding with 3 replicas.
Is this possible at all? What database engines can be used for this purpose(preferably sql dbs)? Did you have any experience?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you have not adequately explained why you are trying this strange topology.

Anyway, I will point out several things relating to MySQL/MariaDB.

- A Galera cluster already embodies multiple nodes (minimum of 3), but does not directly support "sharding".  You can have multiple Galera clusters, one per "shard".
- As with my comment about Galera, other forms of MySQL/MariaDB can have replication between nodes of each shard.
- If you are thinking of having a server with all data, but replicate only parts to *readonly* Replicas, there are settings for replicate_do/ignore_database.  I emphasize "readonly" because changes to these pseudo-shards cannot easily be sent back to the Primary server.  (However see "multi-source replication")
- Sharding is used primarily when there is simply too much traffic to handle on a single server.  Are you saying that the 3 tenants cannot coexist because of excessive writes?  (Excessive reads can be handled by replication.)

A tentative solution:

Have all data on all servers.  Use the same Galera cluster for all nodes.

Advantage:  When "most" or all of the network is working all data is quickly replicated bidirectionally.

Potential disadvantage:  If half or more of the nodes go down, you have to manually step in to get the cluster going again.

Likely solution for the 'disadvantage':  "Weight" the nodes differently.  Give a height weight to the 3 in HQ; give a much smaller (but non-zero) weight to each branch node.  That way, most of the branches could go offline without losing the system as a whole.

But...  I fear that an offline branch node will automatically become readonly.

Another plan:

Switch to NDB.  The network is allowed to be fragile.  Consistency is maintained by "eventual consistency" instead of the "[virtually] synchronous replication" of Galera+InnoDB.

NDB allows you to immediately write on any node.  Then the write is sent to the other nodes.  If there is a conflict one of the values is declared the "winner".  You choose which algorithm for determining the winner.  An easy-to-understand one is "whichever write was 'first'".